# multicolumn in array environment

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to create a matrix like the following in a math environment
but i keep getting compile errors.

```
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{R} & P \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
```

Comment: It works perfectly with me. Please, provide a full [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the compile error message(s) you're getting? (You're missing \\ at the end of the second array line, but I assume that's not the error you're most concerned with.) Please also indicate the document class you're using, and whether you're using packages such as `array` that affect the properties of the `array` environment.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't entered `mathmode` using either `$...$` or `\[...\]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following runs without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{R} & P \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]