# Title over multicolumn array and side-by-side arrays

Tags: beamer, multicolumn, arrays, greek

I want to add in a presentation (beamer) 4 multicolumn (4 columns each) arrays side-by-side and give a title over each array. What I tried for my article was this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{array, multicol}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,alphabeta }
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4} 
\paragraph*{ {$P\wedgeQ$}}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        %\multicolumn{}{c}{R}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&N&F\\
        \hline
        F&F&F&F
    \end{array}$
\paragraph*{ {$P\veeQ$}}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&T&T\\
        \hline
        N&T&N&N\\
        \hline
        F&T&N&F
    \end{array}$
\paragraph*{ {$P\rightarrowQ$}}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&T&\boxed{T}&N\\
        \hline
        F&T&T&T
    \end{array}$
\paragraph*{ {$P\leftrightarrowQ$}}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&\boxed{T}&N\\
        \hline
        F&F&N&T
    \end{array}$
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't look like in the photo (one column is missing from the photo).

[image]

Could anyone help? I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70737) answer but when trying to mimic it the two first arrays bump into each other a bit and letter P changes to greek P (I have a bilingual text, with main language being greek).
I don't want the title to in the exact position (it could be left centered, right, in the middle) as in the photo, but the letters are too apart and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you use `extbook` and multicols if you want to add it to your beamer presentation? Beamer has its own column mechanism.

Comment: Can you show an actual beamer example so we can see which aspect ratio and theme you use to know how much space the columns will have?

Comment: Is something like https://pastebin.com/aw8cqn3k what you are looking for?

Comment: I had written the article extbook class because I wanted some font sizes not available in ordinary class). I will update the code with the beamer code.

Comment: Yes like the code you sent. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know for the column environment in beamer. It is my first day using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beamer's own column mechanism:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{title}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&N&F\\
        \hline
        F&F&F&F
    \end{array}$
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{title}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&N&F\\
        \hline
        F&F&F&F
    \end{array}$
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{title}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&N&F\\
        \hline
        F&F&F&F
    \end{array}$
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.23\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{title}
    $\begin{array}{c|c c c}
        P\backslash Q& T & N & F\\
        \hline
        T&T&N&F\\
        \hline
        N&N&N&F\\
        \hline
        F&F&F&F
    \end{array}$
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to fix the code for the article class?

Comment: @ΝικολέταΣεβαστού You should ask about the article class in a separate question